# how to place some label on some window?

Tags: objective-c, nswindow, nsimage

I need to mark some opened window from my application. I can get the windows list, their system id, name, owner... Can I draw some NSImage only on choosen window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a window, as you say you do, you could add a `NSImageView` as a subview of that window. This `NSImageView` should be set to have a frame the same size as the window in question so it fills the window.

If you need to do custom drawing you could subclass the `NSImageView` and override its `drawRect:` method or you could just set its image property to an image that you have already created and added to the apps bundle.

Hope this is what you mean.